# Issue with Java SSLSocket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, networking, sslsocketfactory

I'm currently working on a client-server project.
I've decided I should use SSL for security reasons.

I tried converting all `Socket` and `ServerSocket` objects to their SSL variants, but to no avail.
When I use the `SSLServerSocket` and connect to it, socket output on the server-side freezes in the middle of `outputstream.write(byte[])`.

Here are the functions I use to create the SSL Sockets,
`ContextController.CONTEXT` is the `SSLContext` and `Constants.DEBUG` is a fast way for me to toggle SSL:

```
public static ServerSocket server(int port, int backlog) throws IOException {
    return Constants.DEBUG ? new ServerSocket(port, backlog) : CONTEXT.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(port, backlog);
}

public static Socket client(InetSocketAddress address) throws IOException {
    return Constants.DEBUG ? new Socket(address.getHostName(), address.getPort())
            : ContextController.CONTEXT.getSocketFactory().createSocket(address.getHostName(), address.getPort());
}

public static Socket client() throws IOException {
    return Constants.DEBUG ? new Socket() : ContextController.CONTEXT.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}
```

When `Constants.DEBUG = true` (i.e. SSL is off) it works, but when SSL is on it freezes as stated above after sending some data indefinitely. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**:
Here is the source of `ContextController.CONTEXT`:
(note, I know I should use an actual `TrustManager` but first I want this to work)

```
    if (server) {// load the keystore
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ks)) {
            CONTEXT = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            // load the keystore from the file
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keystore.load(fis, PASSWORD);

            // setup the KeyManagerFactory (used by the server)
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keystore, PASSWORD);

            CONTEXT.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    else {
        CONTEXT = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        CONTEXT.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        } }, null);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**:
Here is a stacktrace of where it freezes, note it doesn't crash, it hangs:

```
Thread [ClientExecThread #0] (Suspended)    
owns: AppOutputStream  (id=54)  
owns: ByteArrayOutputStream  (id=55)    
SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]   
SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(byte[], int, int) line: 111  
SocketOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: 155    
OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputStream, byte[], int, int, int) line: 431 
OutputRecord.write(OutputStream, boolean, ByteArrayOutputStream) line: 417  
SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(OutputRecord, boolean) line: 876  
SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(OutputRecord, boolean) line: 847  
AppOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: 123   
ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(OutputStream) line: 167   
SocketStream.streamPacket(Packet) line: 181 
ClientThread.lambda$8(Group) line: 150  
1427646530.run(Object) line: not available  
ClientThread.execute() line: 444    
ClientThread$ClientExecThread.run() line: 261
```

I've placed a breakpoint the line after `SocketStream.streamPacket(Packet) 181` and it never reaches it.

Comment: Can we see how ContextController.CONTEXT looks like?

Comment: Use `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");` instead of `"SSL"`. Also, implement the `TrustManager`, as you are defining a server. As you haven't provided any errors, it's hard to tell what is actually happening.

Comment: That's the problem, there is no error. It just freezes.

Comment: Is the peer doing any reading?

Comment: I concur most likely case is the peer isn't reading (enough or at all) although it could be something in the network in between. If server is Unix `netstat` or `ss` should show if you have a large send-Q. In all cases since you control the server and presumably its privatekey if you force plain-RSA ciphers (by re/configuring either or both peer(s)) Wireshark can decrypt the session and show you what data is sent _and_ if you are getting TCP responses at all and if and what they ACK and whether they open or close the receiver window.

Comment: The peer is reading in a loop, so it waits for the server to send data, and beyond that, Java's OutputStream.write() doesn't wait for reading. Wireshark could be a nice idea to see if it sends the data before freezing, I'll try that now.

Comment: Java SocketOutputStream calls the OS TCP/IP stack to send, which blocks if the send buffer is full and the receiver is not accepting (ACK-ing) data.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I have no clue why the client wouldn't ACK, but this seems to be the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I really don't know why this happened and I don't need all aspects of SSL (only the encryption part, that why I didn't implement the `TrustManager`) so I decided to implement a Diffie Hellman instead.

This works as intended and combining the DH with AES I have encrypted traffic per my requirements.

Thank you everyone for you help!